# Sending multiple Pandas DataFrames .to_csv() in a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have five DataFrames, `df1`, `df2`, `df3`, `df4`, `df5`.

I can save each one individually with:

```
df1.to_csv('~/Desktop/df1.tsv', index=False, header=False, sep='\t')
df2.to_csv('~/Desktop/df2.tsv', index=False, header=False, sep='\t')
...
```

**Can I do this in a loop where the file path ends with the name of the variable that holds the Dataframe?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you say

> the name of the DataFrame

do you mean the name of the variable that holds the dataframe? that won't work.

but here's something that *will* work:

```py
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]
for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
   df.to_csv(f'~/Desktop/df{i}.tsv', index=False, header=False, sep='\t')
```

if you wanted unique names

```py
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]
names = ["apple", "bananna", "cherry", "drizz", "ebola"]
for name, df in zip(names, dfs):
   df.to_csv(f'~/Desktop/df{name}.tsv', index=False, header=False, sep='\t')
```

Comment: Rereading your answer, if I wanted to save the DataFrames with unique names, e.g. apple, orange, peach, pear - is this possible? So instead of df1,df2,dfN, what if the variable names were apple, orange, peach, etc.

Comment: @TipsyHyena easy. check the answer